# Excel VBA Formula - 1004 object or application defined error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm adding a macro to allow the user to change the formula in a cell.
Here is the code that added to a module:

```
Sub OverrideCharge()

title = "Override Total Labor Cost"

'Ask user if they want to override
overrideMsg = MsgBox("Override Total Labor Cost with 4-Hour Minimum Charge?", vbYesNo, title)
If overrideMsg = vbYes Then
    Sheets("Totals").Activate
    Range("L25").Formula = "=SUM(IF(MOD(ROW(INDIRECT(""L11:L""&ROW()-1)),2)=1,INDIRECT(""L11:L""&ROW()-1),0)))"
Else: overrideMsg = vbNo
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

I get the error when defining the `Range("L25").Formula`. I don't know if it's a syntax error or if I'm referencing the sheet/cell incorrectly.

Comment: Does the formula work when you manually enter the formula into a cell?

Comment: Try with `Range("L25").Formula = "=SUM(IF(MOD(ROW(INDIRECT(L11:L & ROW()-1)),2)=1,INDIRECT(L11:L & ROW()-1),0))"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get your quote marks & brackets sorted, should be:

```
Range("L25").Formula = "=SUM(IF(MOD(ROW(INDIRECT(""L11:L""&(ROW()-1))),2)=1,INDIRECT(""L11:L""&(ROW()-1)),0))"
```

Comment: Thank you. The original formula worked as an actual Excel formula, but I didn't know it needed to be edited a bit for VBA.

Answer (score 0):

When working with long complex formulas I like adding a FormulaString variable to help me debug (this way I can see better where the error is coming from).

Also, there is no need to `Activate` the `Sheets("Totals")`, and then placing the formula in Cell L25, you can do it directly with `Sheets("Totals").Range("L25").Formula`.

My own preference, instead of starting to count how many `"` , or `""` , or maybe `""""` I need, I like working with `Chr(34)`.

**Code**

```
Sub OverrideCharge()

Dim FormStr As String
Title = "Override Total Labor Cost"

'Ask user if they want to override
overrideMsg = MsgBox("Override Total Labor Cost with 4-Hour Minimum Charge?", vbYesNo, Title)
If overrideMsg = vbYes Then
    ' use a String for Formula to help debug it (before trying to put it inside a cell)
    FormStr = "=SUM(IF(MOD(ROW(INDIRECT(" & Chr(34) & "L11:L" & Chr(34) & "&ROW()-1)),2)=1,INDIRECT(" & Chr(34) & "L11:L" & Chr(34) & "&ROW()-1),0))"
    Debug.Print FormStr '<-- for debug only
    Sheets("Totals").Range("L25").Formula = FormStr
Else
    overrideMsg = vbNo
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```